# Change the date to fiscal year

Tags: excel, date, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2007

I want to write a function in Excel to change the date. The logic is like this: if the month is (Jan, Feb or March) the result show me one year past (-1 year) and if the month is (April to -December) the result show the current year (which year the date shows).

> example: if date is 02,Jan,2012 the result show me 2011 else show me 2012.

Comment: Note your example is inconsistent with the spec. Did you mean 2012?

Comment: Are you trying to convert to [fiscal year](http://www.contextures.com/fiscalyearcalculations.html)?

Comment: @zx8754 yes i want to convert it to fiscal year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract [fiscal year](http://www.contextures.com/fiscalyearcalculations.html) use:

```
=YEAR(A1) + IF(MONTH(A1)>=4,1,0)
```

I think in your case you would need:

```
=YEAR(A1) - IF(MONTH(A1)>=4,0,1)
```

If the months is before 4th month then subtract 1 year, else keep the same year. I wouldn't convert it to a full date `DD/MM/YYYY` with a 1 year subtracted, to avoid confusion keep it as year only `YYYY`.

Comment: This is the answer =IF(OR(MONTH(E6)=1,MONTH(E6)=2,MONTH(E6)=3),YEAR(E6)-1&"-"&YEAR(E6),YEAR(E6)&"-"&YEAR(E6)+1).

Answer (score 3):

`=IF(MONTH(G3) >=4, YEAR(G3), YEAR(G3) - 1)` where `G3` is the date to test, is one way.

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
=IF(OR(MONTH(A1)=1,MONTH(A1)=2,MONTH(A1)=3),2011,2012)
```

Comment: Plus one. A sensible solution to an ill-formed spec that will probably require tweaks.

Answer (score 2):

With *02-Jan-2012* in A1 try,

```
=YEAR(A1)-(MONTH(A1)<4)
```

For a full date use one of these,

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1)-(MONTH(A1)<4), MONTH(A1), DAY(A1))
=EDATE(A1, -(MONTH(A1)<4)*12)
```

Answer (score 1):

Already plenty of answers, but thought I'd throw another one up:

```
=YEAR(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)-3,DAY(A1)))
```

Comment: Are you sure that works on say 31-May? Then it will try to formulate a date based on 31-Feb. I'm not sure how well-defined that is.